# Issue with opacity fade in CSS

Tags: css, animation, transition

I have an issue in CSS while trying to fade in some elements in CSS. 
I would like to show with a fade in effect some elements in my image right after the rotate transition but it doesn't work.

I did a jsfiddle and you can activate the effect with an hover on the image :
https://jsfiddle.net/egfjp36h/

Here's my HTML code :

```
<div class="flip-box">
    <div class="fut-player-card card-display">
        <div class="fut-front">
            <div class="player-card-top player-card-top-color">
                <div class="player-master-info">
                    <div class="player-rating">
                        <span>97</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="player-position">
                        <span>RW</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="player-nation">
                        <img src="https://selimdoyranli.com/cdn/fut_card/img/argentina.svg" alt="Argentina" draggable="false">
                    </div>
                    <div class="player-club">
                        <img src="https://selimdoyranli.com/cdn/fut_card/img/barcelona.svg" alt="Barcelona" draggable="false">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="player-picture">
                    <img src="https://selimdoyranli.com/cdn/fut_card/img/messi.png" alt="Messi" draggable="false">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="player-card-bottom">
                <div class="player-info player-info-color">

                    <div class="player-name player-name-border"><span>MESSI</span></div>

                    <div class="player-features">
                        <div class="player-features-col player-features-col-border">
                            <span>
                                <div class="player-feature-value">97</div>
                                <div class="player-feature-title">RDV</div>
                            </span>
                            <span>
                                <div class="player-feature-value">95</div>
                                <div class="player-feature-title">CTR</div>
                            </span>
                            <span>
                                <div class="player-feature-value">94</div>
                                <div class="player-feature-title">TRANSF</div>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="player-features-col player-features-col-border">
                            <span>
                                <div class="player-feature-value">99K€</div>
                                <div class="player-feature-title">CA</div>
                            </span>
                            <span>
                                <div class="player-feature-value">35</div>
                                <div class="player-feature-title">DEF</div>
                            </span>
                            <span>
                                <div class="player-feature-value">68</div>
                                <div class="player-feature-title">PHY</div>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

And my CSS :

```
         .fut-player-card{
            position: relative;
            width:300px;
            height:485px;
            background-position: center center;
            background-size:100% 100%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            padding:5.9rem 0;
            z-index: 2;
            transition: 200ms ease-in; 
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }

        .card-display{
            background-image: url(https://selimdoyranli.com/cdn/fut_card/img/card_bg.png);
        }

        .card-display2{
            background-image: url("img/fut/fut1.png");
        }

        .card-display3{
            background-image: url("img/fut/fut2.png");
        }

        .card-display4{
            background-image: url("img/fut/fut3.png");
        }

        .player-card-top{
            position: relative;
            display: flex;
            padding: 0 3.5rem;
        }

        .player-master-info{
            position: absolute;
            line-height: 3.2rem;
            font-weight: 300;
            padding: 3rem 0;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }

        .player-rating{
            font-size:3rem;
        }

        .player-position{
            font-size: 2.2rem;
        }

        .player-nation{
            display: block;
            width:3rem;
            height:25px;
            margin: 0.5rem 0;
        }

        .player-nation img{
            width:100%;
            height: 100%;
            object-fit: contain;
        }

        .player-club{
            display: block;
            width:3.1rem;
            height:40px;
        }

        .player-club img{
            width:100%;
            height: 100%;
            object-fit: contain;
        }

        .player-picture{
            width:200px;
            height:200px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .player-picture img{
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            object-fit: contain;
            position: relative;
            right: -1.5rem;
            bottom: 0;
        }

        .player-extra{
            position: absolute;
            right:0;
            bottom: -0.5rem;
            overflow: hidden;
            font-size:1rem;
            font-weight: 700;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            width:100%;
            height:2rem;
            padding:0 1.5rem;
            text-align: right;
            background:none;
        }

        .player-extra span{
            margin-left: 0.6rem;
            text-shadow:2px 2px #333;
        }

        .player-card-bottom{
            position: relative;
        }

        .player-info{
            display: block;
            padding:1rem 0;
            width:90%;
            margin:0 auto;
            height: auto;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 2;
        }

        .player-info-color, .player-card-top-color{
            color:#e9cc74;
        }

        .player-info-color2, .player-card-top-color2{
            color:#130d40;
        }

        .player-name{
            width:100%;
            display: block;
            text-align: center;
            font-size:2.2rem;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            padding-bottom: 0.3rem;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .player-name-border{
            border-bottom: 2px solid; 
            border-color: rgba(233,204,116, 0.1);
        }

        .player-name-border2{
            border-bottom: 2px solid; 
            border-color: rgba(13, 33, 74, 0.2);
        }

        .player-name span{
            display: block;
            text-shadow:2px 2px #111;
        }

        .player-name2 span{
            display: block;
            text-shadow:2px 2px #fff;
        }

        .player-features{
            margin: 1rem auto;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        .player-features-col{
            border-right: 2px solid;
            padding: 0 3rem;
        }

        .player-features-col-border{
            border-color: rgba(233,204,116, 0.1);
        }

        .player-features-col-border2{
            border-color: rgba(13,33,74, 0.2);
        }

        .player-features-col span{
            display: flex;
            font-size: 2rem;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }

        .player-feature-value{
            margin-right: 1rem;
            font-weight: 700;
        }

        .player-feature-title{
            font-weight: 300;
        }

        .player-features-col:last-child{
            border:0;
        }

        .flip-box {
            perspective: 1000px;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .fut-player-card{
            position: relative;
            text-align: center;
            transition: transform 0.8s;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
        }

        .flip-box:hover .fut-player-card{
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
        }

        .flip-box:hover .fut-front{
            filter: alpha(opacity=100);
            opacity:1;
        }

        .fut-front{
            position: absolute;
        }

        .fut-front{
            transition: opacity 0.8s linear 1.2s;
            filter: alpha(opacity=0);
            opacity: 0;
        }
```

I thought it was OK with those elements but the transition is effective when the mouse leave the image and not when the mouse comes over the image :

```
        .flip-box:hover .fut-front{
            filter: alpha(opacity=100);
            opacity:1;
        }

        .fut-front{
            transition: opacity 0.8s linear 1.2s;
            filter: alpha(opacity=0);
            opacity: 0;
        }
```

EDIT : It works on Firefox but not on Chrome

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but when I hover over the image, the stats show up after 1.2 seconds on hover, then when I hover off, the stats disappear after 1.2s. Seems to work exactly as programmed.

Comment: @disinfor i don't get the transition property because i don't want the stats to appear brutally but with a fade effect after the rotate one completed.

Comment: This is what happens when I hover: the image spins and the stats fade in. When I mouse out, the image spins and then the stats fade out.

Comment: @disinfor Thanks for your answer. In the jsfiddle link in my post, i don't see the fade effect when I hover, I only see it when I mouse out. However, if you change the rotate value to 360 instead of 180 it works perfectly... But i want to make it perform for a 180° rotation

Comment: Which browser are you seeing the problem in? In Firefox 69, I see the same fading behavior as @disinfor.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane, you're right. It works as expected on Firefox, but I'm using chrome and the behavior is absolutly different...

Answer (score 0):

You can select the element with javascript and add:

```
addEventListener("mouseenter", function( event ) { 
//change opacity here
})
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I'll use it as a last resort but i would like to succeed in CSS because i know it's possible to do the trick in CSS.